# How can I add links to my custom javascript image swap?

Tags: javascript

I have a div that I am calling slideshow

```
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="images/imageslider/Pic1.jpg" style="width:270px;" alt="" />
<img src="images/imageslider/Pic2.jpg" style="width:270px;" alt="" />
<img src="images/imageslider/Pic3.jpg" style="width:270px;" alt="" />
</div>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
: $('#slideshow IMG:first');
$active.addClass('last-active');
$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
.addClass('active')
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
$active.removeClass('active last-active');
});
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 6000 );
});
```

What is happening is that when I change

```
<img src="images/imageslider/Pic1.jpg" style="width:270px;" alt="" />
```

to

```
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="images/imageslider/Pic1.jpg" style="width:270px;" alt="" /></a>
```

The script causes the function to behave choppy. Instead of fading into the next pic with a link it jumps and not in the predefined order.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: @Diodeus if I use wrap, how do I differentiate links from one link to the next if pics 1-3 are supposed to link out to different pages?

Comment: Try to call it on the links: `$('#slideshow a.active');`

Comment: @user1157575 that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call it on the links:

```
function slideSwitch() 
{
    var $active = $('#slideshow a.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow a:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow a:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() 
        {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}
```